# NullPointerException when getting AppBarLayout and call setFitsSystemWindows()

Tags: android

I am trying to make StatusBar transparent. Here's `setTransparentStatusbar()`:

```
public void setTransparentStatusbar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_appbar);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        appBarLayout.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
        toolbar.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
        toolbar.getLayoutParams().height = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_height) + SizeUtil.getStatusBarHeight(this);
    }
}
```

I use class BaseActivity to set up toolbars for all child activities. In child activities' `onCreate()` I use `super.setContentViewAndSetUpToolBar()` instead of `setContentView()`, Here's parts of `setContentViewAndSetUpToolBar(int layoutResID)`:

```
setContentView(layoutResID);
//        Init Toolbar
    androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar_lower = (androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar_lower);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Set ic icon
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.twotone_event_note_white_24);
    }
setTransparentToolbar();
```

Here's main_toolbar.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:visibility="visible"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_div"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_title"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Here's activity's xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_coordinatorlayout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/circle_one_appbar"
            layout="@layout/main_toolbar"/>



        <!--Main layout-->
        ...
        <!--Main layout END-->

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/circle_one_drawer"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When I call `setTransparentStatusbar()`, program throws NullPointerException, here's error info:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.setFitsSystemWindows(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.elmliu.uniport.activity.BaseActivity.setTransparentToolbar(BaseActivity.java:532)
    at com.example.elmliu.uniport.activity.BaseActivity.setContentViewAndSetUpToolBar(BaseActivity.java:101)
    at com.example.elmliu.uniport.activity.visual.CircleThree.onCreate(CircleThree.java:34)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
```

Comment: Can you show the whole activity code?

Comment: whenever you use Appbar layout make sure that wrap up in Coordinate layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
In main_toolbar.xml, id `main_appbar` was given. However,

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/circle_one_appbar"
        layout="@layout/main_toolbar"/>
```

the new id `circle_one_appbar` will overwrite the old id. Thus, I shouldn't use id `main_appbar` to find the AppBarLayout.